# Why does my c++ fibonacci sequence code give negative values after 46 iterations

Tags: c++, for-loop, fibonacci

The code also doesn't work whenever I try to take out the first two iterations out of the for loop. When I do, I get incredibly high numbers and then 0s for 11 iterations and my i value doesn't change. It has a vector size of 3 at the start of the loop for some reason as well, but it might have to do with the fact that it still wants to add together 0 + 0 for the first term. The error it makes is it adds the two correct values up and somehow ends up with a negative integer. This throws all other values off for the rest of the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){

    std::vector<int> vector;
    vector.push_back(0);
    vector.push_back(1);

    for (int i=0; i <= 47; i++) {
        if (i < 1) {
            std::cout << vector[i] << ", \n";
        }
        vector.push_back(vector[i] + vector[i + 1]);
        std::cout << vector[i] << " = " << vector[i-2] << " + " << vector[i-1] << ":  " << "vector size" << vector.size() << ", \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: The size 3 thing really shouldn't be unexpected. Before the loop, you push back 2 elements. Then in the *line directly above** your `std::cout`, you push back another element. Worth noting, that's not the start of the loop, it's the end of your first iteration.

Comment: You'll also see garbage values for the first few iterations because `i - 2` and `i - 1` will lead to negative indices. Also, `i <= 47` means you'll iterate 47 times, not 46.

Comment: Actually 48 times.

Comment: True. I guess I got hung up on the 46 in the headline.

Comment: Instead of using `[i-2]` and `[i-1]` in the `cout` line, which is wrong as pointed out by sweenish, you could have used `[i]` and `[i + 1]`, just like you do in `vector.push_back`.

Comment: Please don't name your variables the same as standard classes like you did with `vector`.  That's going to get you in big trouble some day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative values should have been a big hint to you. An `int` has a maximum value of `2147483647`. You overflow the `int` and it wraps around to being negative.

If you use a bigger type, like `std::uint64_t`, you can postpone the overflow by a decent amount. Its maximum value is: `18446744073709551615`.

Finally, printing in the loop creates a lot of repetition that can be hard to decipher. Just print your vector after the loop is complete, and test with a smaller number of iterations to ensure that your algorithm is functioning properly.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::uint64_t> vector{0, 1};

  for (int i = 0; i < 47; i++) {
    vector.push_back(vector[i] + vector[i + 1]);
  }

  for (auto i : vector) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The for loop creating the sequence iterates **47** times, so double-check your requirements.

Comment: Ah I completely forgot about the maximum value. It’s my first time trying to find such large numbers. Would I still have to specify that it’s a C++11 file to initialize the first two vector values in that way? I got an error the first time I tried, but it might just be that I have an earlier version.

Comment: @MekhiEdwards note that even with `uint64_t` you're going to overflow at 94.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much C++, but from what I can tell, you're using an `int`, signed integers typically range from **-2,147,483,648** to **2,147,483,647**. The 47th number in the Fibonacci sequence is **2,971,215,073**, so that's more than you can store in an int. When you **overflow** it (go beyond its limit) you get all kinds of nonsense. Well, not actually nonsense, when you go one number beyond the limit,  2,147,483,648 for example, you should get -2,147,483,648 (you go one up from the smallest number), so the amount you went over the limit is the offset from the lowest number (-2,147,483,648). Same happens if you try to store a number way too small (underflow), it will become positive once below the lowest number.

In your case, you need, at least, an unsigned int, and to store bigger numbers, you have `long int`, `long long int` and `unsigned long long int`